# jquery form submission not working

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit

i'm using jquery-1.10.1 and my HTML code is:

```
<li>
  <a href='' id='logout'>Log Out</a></li>
    <form id='logout_form' method='post'>
     <input type='hidden' name='logout' value='true' />
    </form>
```

my jquery code is this which is at the end of every document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#logout").click(function(){
        $("#logout_form").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

and my php code is this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['logout'])){
    $object=new logout();
    $content='5;url='.$path.'index.php';
}
```

but my form submission is not working. anybody pls help me.

Comment: here `$path` meant for depth of the page from root, `$content` is used in a meta tag. `logout` is a class which is defined in another file which is included in every page.

Comment: Please define "is not working" - does it fails to make request, script error, server side code error, you don't like how code is written, something else.

Comment: when i click on the link nothing happens. if there is any error in my php code, i should get error. but the controller doesn't goes to that part. so most probably form submission is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is href=' ' Attribute, remove it

Change this:

```
<a href='' id='logout'>Log Out</a>
```

For this:

```
<a id='logout'>Log Out</a>
```

you can add some css to avoid lost pointer cursor

```
<style>
   a{cursor:pointer}
</style>
```

You can and should change the anchor for a div or span and add some css

UPDATE:
The code I used:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9">
        <title></title>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#logout").click(function(){
                    $("#logout_form").submit();
                });
            });

        </script>
        <?php
        if (!empty($_POST['logout'])) {
            echo 'hola.<br>';
        }else{
            echo 'Wrong.<br>';
        }

        ?>
    </head>
    <a  id='logout'>Log Out</a></li>
<form id='logout_form' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='logout' value='true' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Outpout after click on Log out:

```
hola 
Log Out
```

Comment: most of the forms i'm using in my project have missing action as they post to same page only. and all of them work very fine.

Comment: nearly all of them are visible, so i don't need a jquery form submission for them. i use normal `input type='submit'`

Comment: i get no error in the console and that alert is working fine.

Comment: in the php do a print_r($_POST); to see if it has any value?

Comment: it doesn't goes to the PHP part. i've tried echoing different strings, even changed some of the variables which should be visible in html body. but nothing is displayed.

Comment: same problem. i'm guessing somehow my form is posting nothing.

Comment: my jquery form submit is not working. i've tried with other forms, and it doesn't submit them.

Comment: thanks. your code works fine alone in a try.php. as soon as i implement it in my project, same problem. arghhhh...

Comment: @RatDon You have the php code to process the form in another page???you have to put `action="try.php"` in the form

Comment: No i'm submitting to the same page, not a different page.